# Access a user control from another control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a store implemented in ASP.NET/C#.  There is a page - `ReservationProduct.aspx` - which has a control to show the product - `BuyTourProduct` - and another control to show product details - `TourProductDetail`.

I know it is good form to keep the two decoupled but this is for a very specific store use.  I want the `BuyTourProduct` to be able to set a panel in the `TourProductDetail` control to be visible or not using `PanelName.Visible=true|false`.

How do I have one control set attributes on a panel in the other control?  I hope I am saying this clearly enough.

By the way, this is a couple of 3rd product controls that I'm modifying so changing the fact that they are 2 separate controls is not really an option for us.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the UserControl, the user control is not aware of the other UserControl or it's contents.  You'll need to interact with the controls at the Page context, because the Page is aware of both controls.

You will need two things:

- An event fired from the BuyTourProduct control.
- A method to interact with the PanelName in the TourProductDetail control.

If an event exists already, use that; otherwise, it will require you to modify the source of the BuyTourProduct, and expose an event and fire that event within that code.  You'll then also want to call this event from within the control.

```
public class BuyTourProduct : UserControl
{
    // ...

    public delegate void MyHideEventDelegate();
    public event MyHideEventDelegate MyHideEvent;

    // ...

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        if (MyHideEvent != null)
            MyHideEvent();
    }

    // ... 
}
```

Next, you'll need to add a method to interact with PanelName inside TourProductDetail:

```
public class TourProductDetail : UserControl
{
    // ...

    private Panel PanelName;

    // ...

    public void SetPanelNameVisible(Boolean visible)
    {
        PanelName.Visible = visible;
    }

    // ...
}
```

From the Page, you'll subscribe to the event you want or the MyHideEvent:

```
public partial class ReservationProduct : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // ...

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buyTourProduct.MyHideEvent += new BuyTourProduct.MyHideEventDelegate(buyTourProduct_MyHideEvent);
    }

    // ...

    void buyTourProduct_MyHideEvent()
    {
        tourProductDetail.SetPanelNameVisible(false);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is always better to write an event inside the user control BuyTourProduct (Ex:Need to update product detail)
Then you can handle in this event in the page where you place the control.

in the TourProductDetail control you can write a public property to hide and show the panel.

So in the above event handler for the BuyTourProduct event handler in the page call the ShowHidePanel property of the TourProductDetail control.

Comment: +1 I am still thinking like a linear program flow coder instead of OOP. Thank you for your method.