# Set <div> visibility in one control from another c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# page with two controls - one is a calendar and the other is information about a product. The scriptlet for the page has:

```
[[ConLib:Reservation/BuyTourProductDialogGalaxy ShowSku="false"]]
```

and

```
<div id="RestOfPage">
    <!-- Show Product Detail Tabs -->
    <div id="TourProductDetails">
        [[ConLib:Custom/MobileTourProductDetails ShowDescription="false" ShowMap="true" ShowDetailsButton="false" DetailsButtonText="See More Details: Schedules, Locations, etc."]] 
    </div>
</div>
```

My task is to cause an event, `btnCheckCalendar_Click()`, in the `BuyTourProductDialogGalaxy` conlib to hide the information in the other conlib... either hide the `MobileTourProductDetails` conlib or the entire `RestOfPage` div.

How can I do that across conlibs?  If it were in the same I'd just `MyThing.visible = false` but `Mything` isn't visible from the other conlib.  I'm guessing I'd need JavaScript but do not know how to pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a public method within your codebehind to set the visibility of your protected field. You would have to set the div tag to runat="server" in order to do this like so...

`<div id="RestOfPage">
    <!-- Show Product Detail Tabs -->
    <div id="TourProductDetails" runat="server">
        [[ConLib:Custom/MobileTourProductDetails ShowDescription="false" ShowMap="true" ShowDetailsButton="false" DetailsButtonText="See More Details: Schedules, Locations, etc."]] 
    </div>
</div>`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe this was a "dumb question"?  I wonder if I can create a public function in the 2nd conlib that is called HideDetails and then call that from the first conlib?  I made one public but when coding the first conlib I don't get any intellisense view on it.  Is that possible to call a public function from another conlib?  If so I have a declaration wrong.  Is that what you mean here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm losing my mind.  I already asked this question and got a great answer from [Walk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028105/walk) under [Access a user control from another control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503644/access-a-user-control-from-another-control).  Too many projects and not enough time or brains I guess.